# ggplot2 - highlight area between two geom_circle

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have encountered a problem where I need to layer two plots, being a scatterplot and a donut chart.

If using a regular donut chart in ggplot2, the scale is completely changed and I am unable to layer a scatterplot over it.

My solution was to create two circles with geom_circle, and highlight/shade the area between the circles, however, I am struggling to get it to work.

This might not be the ideal solution, so any advice would be greatly appreciated at this stage.

```
    #
    # load packages
    #

    library(tidyverse)        
    library(ggplot2)
    library(ggforce)


    #
    # create test data 
    #

    x <- c(5,-3,2,-1,7,-1, 4,-6)
    y <- c(3, 5,8,-2,3, 2,-7,-1)
    instance <- c('Positive','Positive','Positive','Positive','Negative', 'Negative', 'Negative','Negative')
    df <- data.frame(x, y, instance)
    df_circle_1 <- data.frame(x=0,y=0, r=5)
    df_circle_2 <- data.frame(x=0,y=0, r=7)


    #
    # create circle plot - 1
    #

    p <- ggplot() + geom_circle(data=df_circle_1, 
                                aes(x0=x,
                                    y0=y,
                                    r=r), 
                                linetype="dashed", 
                                size=1,
                                colour="darkgrey")

    #
    # add circle plot - 2
    #

    p <- p + geom_circle(data=df_circle_2, 
                                aes(x0=x,
                                    y0=y,
                                    r=r), 
                                linetype="dashed", 
                                size=1,
                                colour="darkgrey")



    #
    # add scatterplot 
    #

    p <- p + geom_point(data=df, 
                        aes(x, 
                            y, 
                            color=instance,
                            shape=instance),
                        size=3,) +

      scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(-10, 10, by=1), limits=c(-10,10)) + 
      scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-10, 10, by=1), limits=c(-10,10)) +

      geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = 1) +
      geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = 1) +

      theme(legend.title=element_blank(), 
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
            axis.title.y=element_text(angle=360,vjust=0.5))

    #
    # display chart 
    #

    p
```

Graph I am trying to replicate

[image]

Graph produced by my code

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A hacky proposition for the shading area problem, filling the big circle in green, filling the small circle in white, and setting the panel on top:

```
p <- ggplot() + 
  geom_circle(data=df_circle_2, 
              aes(x0=x,
                  y0=y,
                  r=r), 
              linetype="dashed", 
              fill = "green",
              size=1,
              colour="darkgrey")+ 
  geom_circle(data=df_circle_1, 
                            aes(x0=x,
                                y0=y,
                                r=r), 
                            linetype="dashed", 
                            fill = "white",
                            size=1,
                            colour="darkgrey")+ 

  theme_bw() +theme(
  panel.ontop = TRUE,
  panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA)
)+  geom_point(data=df, 
             aes(x, 
                 y, 
                 color=instance,
                 shape=instance),
             size=3,) 
p
```

[image]

This if far from perfect, and I feel that it could be improved by using different layer, but I don't have the knowledge to do it properly